# How to change a status of a Run in Azure DevOps when it wasn't complete

Tags: testing, azure-devops

When I start a Manual Test Execution via Test Plans -> Test Suite -> Select a Test to execute -> Execute -> Run for web application the "Test & Feedback" browser extension kicks in. When for any reason I don't complete the test execution and just close the "Test & Feedback" window the system creates a new test run which can be found in the "Runs"module and its state will be "In Progress". I want to cancel and/or delete the run or all other runs which I don't need to see and can not figure out the way to do it. Double click on the run opens the run summary and results and there is no way to cancel it. Also, the test result for the test is listed as "unspecified". Looks like a DevOps bug but would like to confirm.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. The issue seemed to be a bug and currently fixed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the "In Progress" state when executing the Test point.

We can only do `read operations` on the interface now.

To change the test run state / delete the test run, you could use Rest API to achieve this.

**Delete the test run**

You could use this Rest API : [Runs - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

**Change the test run state**

You could use this Rest API：[Runs - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

Request Body example:

```
{
  "state": "Aborted"     
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was a bug on Microsoft side and they fixed it.