# Azure Devops - Test Run Managment : resuming in-progress test

Tags: azure, devops, resume, pause

Been trying to figure out how to resume an in-progress test in DevOps without any success.
In screenshot 1, you can see that I have three tests that are in progress, but there doesn't seem to be a way to resume them.

In screenshot 2, you can see that double-clicking on the in-progress test and then viewing test results DevOps shows the test is presently paused.

Reviewing other posts related to pausing and resuming tests or searching for any right-click menus or methods of resuming have not yielded any results.  Looking for help resuming tests.

[screenshot 1 of recent test runs from DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMxhb.png)

[Screenshot 2 of test results tab of a previous in-progress run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbMBq.png)

Comment: There does seem to be a distinction in DevOps between clicking pause and then save and close, vs. just save and close.  However, I doesn't make sense to label something as in-progress if it can't be resumed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is not possible to resume the test run in question. The only solution I have seen for this is to delete the test run. The test run deletion can only be done via the Rest API as answered here: [How to change a status of a Run in Azure DevOps when it wasn't complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542454/how-to-change-a-status-of-a-run-in-azure-devops-when-it-wasnt-complete)

This doesn't say much if you don't know how to use a Rest API. User @ATCCAN mentioned in the comments of that question that this issue is a bug from Azure DevOps and that *it is already solved*. I however, have experienced this same issue in the days surrounding this post. It seems to me that the bug still persists.

Research from different has lead me to the conclusion that this is a bug and that it hasn't been solved.

Here is a program to delete test runs using the Rest API:
https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/207/rest-api-delete-test-run.html